# Generating a dynamic sentence from an array with link-to

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Say I have an array like:

```
var values = [
  Ember.Object.create({id: 1, name: 'One'}),
  Ember.Object.create({id: 2, name: 'Two'}),
  Ember.Object.create({id: 3, name: 'Three'})
];
```

I would like to create a sentence that links to each of the different objects. The output would generate something like:

```
{{link-to 'One' 'my-route' 1}}, {{link-to 'Two' 'my-route' 2}}, and {{link-to 'Three' 'my-route' 3}}
```

which would output a sentence, where each of the words links to a different route:

```
One, Two, and Three
```

Is it possible to do this dynamically? I know how to create a dynamic list of links if I'm just iterating over the array ([see example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jevohojoqo/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```
{{#each item in values}}
  <li>{{link-to item.name 'my-route' item.id}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

But this doesn't give me the flexibility to create a comma-separated list with 'and' at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a computed property to give a bit of extra information. Assuming that `values` is a property on a controller:

```
listValues: function() {
    return this.get('values').map(function(item, index, array) {
        return {
            item: item,
            isLastItem: index === array.length - 1
        };
    });
}.property('values.[]')
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#each listValues}}
    {{#if isLastItem}}
        and <li>{{link-to item 'my-route' item.id}}</li>
    {{else}}
        {{! Notice the trailing comma }}
        <li>{{link-to item 'my-route' item.id}}</li>,
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can create a computed property which is all your items except for the last item, and another computed property to return the last item.

Then, in your code you #each through all items but the last one, and then do `and {{lastItem}}`. For example:

```
{{#each item in allButLast}}
  {{link-to item.name 'test' item.id}}, 
{{/each}}

and {{link-to lastItem.name 'test' lastItem.id}}
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeqehayexu/6/) as an example.